# How to remove the known background from captcha in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing

For example, there are two pictures.

Captcha:
[image]

Background:

[image]

How to remove the background from the captcha in c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One simple method is:** You can iterate the image's pixels.
For every pixel, you will need to *subtract* the background pixel value from the original corresponding pixel value.
However, as simple as this method is, it does not detect any edges and does not separate the foreground with the background. Therefore, you will see dots in the resulted image, as they are the result of subtraction from the black dots of the background.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoY7J.jpg)

In order to achieve something like this with C#, you will need an image processing library. If you don't have one, you can look [here](http://csharp-station.com/4-best-c-libraries-for-image-processing/) for details.

If you do not want to use this method, you can look up for edge detection algorithms, but these are quite difficult. In addition, they are not guaranteed to work properly with these captcha images.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a new capture in your site from google capture verification of different backgrounds that may include pictures like vehicles, Bridges, street signs e.t.c